# gson.fromjson is returning null

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this json coming from the api.

```
{ "Table ":[[ "0 ", "--Please Select-- ",0],
            [ "L ", "APPLICANTS ",1],[ "N ", "CANDIDATES ",2],
            [ "C ", "CLIENTS ",3],[ "M ", "MEMBERS ",4],
            [ "S ", "STAFF ",5]], 
  "Table1 ":[[1, "BY EMAIL "], 
             [3, "BY PUSH "],
             [2, "BY SMS "],
             [4, "CheckIn "],
             [5, "CheckOut "]], 
  "Table2 ":[[ "ADMIN ", "ADMIN "],
             [ "CEO ", "CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER "],
             [ "DON ", "DIRECTOR OF NURSING "],
             [ "FO ", "FINANCE OFFICER "],
             [ "GM ", "GENERAL MANAGER "],
             [ "MGR ", "MANAGER "],
             [ "OFA ", "OFFICER ALLOCATIONS "],
             [ "ORE ", "OFFICER RECRUITMENT "],
             [ "OTH ", "OTHERS "],
             [ "PO ", "PERSONAL ASSISTANT "],
             [ "REC ", "RECEPTIONIST "],
             [ "SO ", "SALES OFFICER "],
             [ "SW ", "SOCIAL WORKER "],
             [ "STAFF ", "STAFF "]], 
  "Table3 ":[], 
  "Table4 ":[[1, "CONTACT OUT "]], 
  "Table5 ":[[ "151504 ", "CONTACT MEMBER ", "LOGCONTMBR "],
             [ "151503 ", "EXTERNAL LOG ", "EXTRLOGONL "],
             [ "151501 ", "INTERNAL LOG ", "INTLOGONLY "],
             [ "151502 ", "SALES LOG ", "SALELOGONL "]], 
  "Table6 ":[], 
  "Table7 ":[], 
  "Table8 ":[[1, "New Client Visit "],
             [2, "Client Visit "]]}
```

and this is the response class I am using to parse the json.It was generated by the jsontopojo plugin.

```
public class RecordDataModel{

@SerializedName("Table ")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> table = null;
@SerializedName("Table1 ")
@Expose
private List<List<Integer>> table1 = null;
@SerializedName("Table2 ")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> table2 = null;
@SerializedName("Table3 ")
@Expose
private List<Object> table3 = null;
@SerializedName("Table4 ")
@Expose
private List<List<Integer>> table4 = null;
@SerializedName("Table5 ")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> table5 = null;
@SerializedName("Table6 ")
@Expose
private List<Object> table6 = null;
@SerializedName("Table7 ")
@Expose
private List<Object> table7 = null;
@SerializedName("Table8 ")
@Expose
private List<List<Integer>> table8 = null;

public List<List<String>> getTable() {
    return table;
}

public void setTable(List<List<String>> table) {
    this.table = table;
}

public List<List<Integer>> getTable1() {
    return table1;
}

public void setTable1(List<List<Integer>> table1) {
    this.table1 = table1;
}

public List<List<String>> getTable2() {
    return table2;
}

public void setTable2(List<List<String>> table2) {
    this.table2 = table2;
}

public List<Object> getTable3() {
    return table3;
}

public void setTable3(List<Object> table3) {
    this.table3 = table3;
}

public List<List<Integer>> getTable4() {
    return table4;
}

public void setTable4(List<List<Integer>> table4) {
    this.table4 = table4;
}

public List<List<String>> getTable5() {
    return table5;
}

public void setTable5(List<List<String>> table5) {
    this.table5 = table5;
}

public List<Object> getTable6() {
    return table6;
}

public void setTable6(List<Object> table6) {
    this.table6 = table6;
}

public List<Object> getTable7() {
    return table7;
}

public void setTable7(List<Object> table7) {
    this.table7 = table7;
}

public List<List<Integer>> getTable8() {
    return table8;
}

public void setTable8(List<List<Integer>> table8) {
    this.table8 = table8;
}

}
```

this is the gson code I am using.

```
RecordDataModel recordDataModel = new Gson().fromJson(reader,RecordDataModel.class);
                        System.out.println("size "+recordDataModel.getTable().get(0).get(0));
```

The `recordDataModel`  is throwing null pointer exception,I know the format is a little abrupt but this is what I have and I have to parse it.

What I might be missing here?

Comment: You probably get the error when parsing the at first table1, you have specified a list of Integers, but we can see on your json that's not the case, you have integers and strings

Comment: @Carnal yeah it could be, what to do in this case?

Comment: post your error log along with the question.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 there was no error log of the gson, when I tried to print the size of the list, then the 'recordDataModel' object is giving null pointer exception.

Comment: @SachinMalik could you try to remove one `.get(0)` from sop

Comment: @akhilesh0707 the problem is that gson is not binding the json to pojo class, that is why the object is throwing null, removing one `.get(0)` wont make any difference.

Comment: @SachinMalik yes you are right,  while binding `fromJson` showing any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165204/discussion-between-sachin-malik-and-akhilesh0707).

Comment: `the problem is that gson is not binding the json to pojo class, that is why the object is throwing null` so try this `RecordDataModel recordDataModel = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(reader,RecordDataModel.class);`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan nope bro, didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

there is Parsing error in your code you need to change your Pojo `Integer` values to `String`

**Error**

> Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "BY EMAIL"

Also, remove one `.get(0)` from `System.out.println()`

```
public class RecordDataModel{

    @SerializedName("Table ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table = null;
    @SerializedName("Table1 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table1 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table2 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table2 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table3 ")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> table3 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table4 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table4 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table5 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table5 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table6 ")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> table6 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table7 ")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> table7 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table8 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table8 = null;

    public List<List<String>> getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(List<List<String>> table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable1() {
        return table1;
    }

    public void setTable1(List<List<String>> table1) {
        this.table1 = table1;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable2() {
        return table2;
    }

    public void setTable2(List<List<String>> table2) {
        this.table2 = table2;
    }

    public List<Object> getTable3() {
        return table3;
    }

    public void setTable3(List<Object> table3) {
        this.table3 = table3;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable4() {
        return table4;
    }

    public void setTable4(List<List<String>> table4) {
        this.table4 = table4;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable5() {
        return table5;
    }

    public void setTable5(List<List<String>> table5) {
        this.table5 = table5;
    }

    public List<Object> getTable6() {
        return table6;
    }

    public void setTable6(List<Object> table6) {
        this.table6 = table6;
    }

    public List<Object> getTable7() {
        return table7;
    }

    public void setTable7(List<Object> table7) {
        this.table7 = table7;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable8() {
        return table8;
    }

    public void setTable8(List<List<String>> table8) {
        this.table8 = table8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your POJO with below class

```
public class RecordDataModel {



    @SerializedName("Table ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table = null;
    @SerializedName("Table1 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table1 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table2 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table2 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table3 ")
    @Expose
    private List<String> table3 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table4 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table4 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table5 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table5 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table6 ")
    @Expose
    private List<String> table6 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table7 ")
    @Expose
    private List<String> table7 = null;
    @SerializedName("Table8 ")
    @Expose
    private List<List<String>> table8 = null;


    public List<List<String>> getTable() {
            return table;
    }

    public void setTable(List<List<String>> table) {
            this.table = table;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable1() {
            return table1;
    }

    public void setTable1(List<List<String>> table1) {
            this.table1 = table1;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable2() {
            return table2;
    }

    public void setTable2(List<List<String>> table2) {
            this.table2 = table2;
    }

    public List<String> getTable3() {
            return table3;
    }

    public void setTable3(List<String> table3) {
            this.table3 = table3;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable4() {
            return table4;
    }

    public void setTable4(List<List<String>> table4) {
            this.table4 = table4;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable5() {
            return table5;
    }

    public void setTable5(List<List<String>> table5) {
            this.table5 = table5;
    }

    public List<String> getTable6() {
            return table6;
    }

    public void setTable6(List<String> table6) {
            this.table6 = table6;
    }

    public List<String> getTable7() {
            return table7;
    }

    public void setTable7(List<String> table7) {
            this.table7 = table7;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getTable8() {
            return table8;
    }

    public void setTable8(List<List<String>> table8) {
            this.table8 = table8;
    }}
```